# Showing that a domain of an operator is dense in $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A : D(A) \subset L^2(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)$, where 
$$D(A) = \{u \in H^2([0,1]) : u(0) = u_x (1) = 0\}.$$
Show that $D(A)$ is dense in $L^2((0, 1))$.

$D(A)$ is dense in $L^2((0, 1))$ if  $$\forall T \in L^2((0, 1)), <T, u> = 0, \forall u \in D(A) \Rightarrow T = 0.$$ 
Let $T \in L^2((0, 1))$ with $<T, u> = 0, \forall u \in D(A)$. From Riesz theorem we have that
$\exists ! v \in L^2((0, 1))$ such that $T u = (u, v) = \int u v, \forall u \in L^2(0, 1)$. So 
$$ <T, u> = 0, \forall u \in D(A) \Leftrightarrow (u, v) = 0, \forall u \in D(A)  \Leftrightarrow \int u v = 0, \forall u \in D(A).$$
How can I show that $v = 0$?

Thank you!

Comment: I would just go ahead and prove that $C^\infty_c((0,1))$ is dense in $L^2((0,1))$.  Since $D(A)$ clearly contains the former set, this suffices.  The proof is via cutoff functions and convolution.

Comment: why $C_c^\infty ( 0, 1 ) \subset D(A)$? Indeed, if $$u, u', u'' \in C_c(0, 1) \Rightarrow u, u', u'' \in L^2(0,1) \Rightarrow u \in H^2(0, 1) ,$$  but $$u \in C_c^\infty (0, 1) \Rightarrow u(0) = u(1) \neq 0.$$  If $$u \in D(A) \Rightarrow u(0) = 0.$$Contradiction.

Comment: I don't understand your logic; the use of arrows instead of words makes it hard to follow.  But note that the subscript $c$ indicates "compact support": $C^\infty_c((0,1))$ is the set of smooth functions whose support is a compact subset of the open interval $(0,1)$.  In particular, if $u \in C^\infty_c((0,1))$ then $u$ vanishes on some neighborhood of 0 and some neighborhood of 1, so $u$ and all its derivatives vanish at 0 and at 1.  In particular $u(0) = u'(1) = 0$.  (Doesn't $u_x$ in your original question denote the derivative?)

Comment: Yes. $u_x = u'$. Thank you for explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator $Af=-f''$ is symmetric on the domain $\mathcal{D}(A)$ specified by you. In fact,
$$
                (Af,f)=-f'\overline{f}|_{0}^{1}+(f',f')=\|f'\|^{2} \ge 0.
$$
Suppose $g \perp \mathcal{D}(A)$. Then the following $f$ is in $\mathcal{D}(A)$ with $(A+I)f=g$:
$$
  f = \cosh(x)\int_{0}^{x}\sinh(t)g(t)dt+\sinh(x)\int_{x}^{1}\cosh(t)g(t)dt \in \mathcal{D}(A).
$$
Hence, $g \perp f$, which gives
$$
       0=(g,f)=((A+I)f,f) \ge \|f\|^{2}.
$$
Therefore $f=0$, which implies $g=Af=0$, and means that $\overline{\mathcal{D}(A)}=L^{2}$.

This is a fairly general sort of method for dealing with operators where you have classic solvability and symmetry.